# Solr query command behaving strange and not according to doc

Tags: solr, lucene

I"m trying to search by field and I have trouble getting it to work. I'm using locally installed Solr 5.2.1 and I imported a bunch of articles as JSON, here's an example of one such object:

```
{
    "title": [
        "Jessica Breen - Yorkshire and the Humber Group"
    ],
    "description": [
        "To long to fit here"
    ],
    "link": [
        "http://www.soci.org/news/volunteers/jessica-breen"
    ],
    "date": [
        "2015-07-10T10:10:51Z"
    ],
    "source": [
        "559f9258adeba7381fd56bbe"
    ],
    "id": "93afc349-5bb2-41e2-a95f-e0894ecaf223",
    "_version_": 1506854794016325600
}
```

And now I'm trying to search by title and I'm basing my knowledge on [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) and [tutorial](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html). These queries find that article:

```
Breen
Jessica Breen
"Jessica Breen"
```

but they search in title and description fields while I want it to search only by title. I tried these unsuccessfully:

```
title:Breen
title:"Breen"
title:"Jessica Breen"
```

Do you have any ideas why search queries wouldn't work as they should?

Comment: whats the default search field mentioned in your schema ? <defaultSearchField></defaultSearchField>

Comment: There is none such field and I don"t think I want it, actually. When I search without specified field, it should search by all fields, but when I specify field, it should search only by that field. Setting default field doesn't seem right in my case.

Comment: change the type of the field title to type="text_general"... and restart it...

Comment: There is no "search all fields" functionality in Solr. You'll either have to supply the name of fields you want to search (through `df` or `qf`), or have a "catch all" field that you use `copyField` to index content into.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you are using the default schema from the Basic_configs.

It has the fieldtype string for the field Title and that will work only if query as "Jessica Breen" and not in case of "Breen" as The StrField type is not analyzed.

So n this case you need to change the fieldType for the field Title.
Change the field type of title to text_ws or text_general

```
<field name="title" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: I added it in ``solr-5.2.1\server\solr\configsets\basic_configs\conf\schema.xml`` and nested it under ``<schema></schema>``, right after all those ``<fieldType>``. I also restarted the server but I see no effect. ``title:Breen`` still returns 0 objects.

Comment: it would be good if your share your schema.. is the fiels title has the indexed="true" stored="true" ? does it show any result for *:*?

Comment: Well, schema is a default one which was created when I installed solr.

Comment: I uploaded my schema to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3uvQFGC2), can you please take a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83520/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-dread-boy).